# Docker Desktop 4.1.0 - Installation Failed on Windows 10: Process InstallerCli.exe exited with code 1

Tags: docker

I tried to install the Docker Desktop 4.1.0 on Windows 10. I folowed the installation [instruction from the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#install-docker-desktop-on-windows)

- Hyper-V is enabled
- WLS-2 is installed

And I'm getting the following error:
[image]

```
Installation Failed
Component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction failed: Process InstallerCli.exe exited with code 1
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext() (
```

The installation log `%LocalAppData%\Docker\install-log.11.txt`:

```
Started on: 2021-10-08 16:18:00.362
File: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "D:\Temp\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" 
[16:18:00.466][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[16:18:00.467][Program] No installation found
[16:18:00.569][InstallWorkflow] Cancel pending background download
[16:18:04.848][InstallWorkflow] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[16:18:04.863][InstallWorkflow] Downloading
[16:18:08.038][InstallWorkflow] Extracting manifest
[16:18:09.562][InstallWorkflow] Manifest found: version=69386, displayVersion=4.1.0, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/appcast.xml
[16:18:09.562][InstallWorkflow] Checking prerequisites
[16:18:10.089][InstallWorkflow] Prompting for optional features
[16:18:16.478][InstallWorkflow] Unpacking artifacts
[16:20:37.590][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[16:20:51.267][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[16:21:00.357][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[16:21:01.235][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[16:21:01.238][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Removing service
[16:21:01.240][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Creating service
[16:21:02.868][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[16:21:02.885][InstallWorkflow-ShortcutAction] Creating shortcut: D:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Docker Desktop.lnk/Docker Desktop
[16:21:02.891][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[16:21:02.893][InstallWorkflow-ShortcutAction] Creating shortcut: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Docker Desktop.lnk/Docker Desktop
[16:21:02.894][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction
[16:21:02.896][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.PathAction
[16:21:03.196][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.PathAction
[16:21:03.360][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction
```

The installation log 2 `%LocalAppData%\Docker\install-log.txt`:

```
Version: 4.1.0 (69386)
Sha1: 05eb8751ac40e465ab6691a9d6db535252f63c0d
Started on: 2021-10-08 16:21:03.710
Resources: D:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Edition: Professional
Id: 2009
Build: 19042
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "D:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\InstallerCli.exe" -i
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[16:21:03.883][Installer         ][Info   ] Preparing upgrade...
[16:21:03.906][HyperV            ][Info   ] Destroy
[16:21:04.488][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Info   ] Destroying distro
[16:21:04.651][Installer         ][Info   ] Prepare upgrade completed successfully
[16:21:04.652][Installer         ][Info   ] Fixing permissions...
[16:21:04.653][Installer         ][Info   ] Deleting directory D:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins
[16:21:04.657][Installer         ][Info   ] removing permission inheritance from D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
[16:21:04.658][Installer         ][Info   ] removing ACLs except for SYSTEM and Administrators from D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
[16:21:04.658][Installer         ][Info   ] granting ReadAndExecute to everyone for D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
[16:21:04.659][Installer         ][Info   ] removing permission inheritance from D:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins
[16:21:04.659][Installer         ][Info   ] removing ACLs except for SYSTEM and Administrators from D:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins
[16:21:04.660][Installer         ][Info   ] granting ReadAndExecute to everyone for D:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins
[16:21:04.660][Installer         ][Info   ] removing permission inheritance from D:\ProgramData\Docker
[16:21:04.660][Installer         ][Info   ] removing ACLs except for SYSTEM and Administrators from D:\ProgramData\Docker
[16:21:04.663][Installer         ][Error  ] Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\Docker\config' is denied.
[16:21:04.722][InstallWorkflow] Installation failed
Exception type: System.Exception, Exception message: Component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction failed: Process InstallerCli.exe exited with code 1, StackTrace:
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
[16:21:04.724][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.PathAction
[16:21:04.919][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.PathAction
[16:21:05.106][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction
[16:21:05.109][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[16:21:05.110][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[16:21:05.111][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[16:21:06.121][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[16:21:06.122][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[16:21:06.123][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[16:21:06.123][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep
[16:21:06.137][FileSystem] Deleting D:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
[16:21:06.333][FileSystem] Deleted D:\Program Files\Docker\Docker successfully
[16:21:06.333][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep
[16:21:06.334][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
```

I also tried to skip the installation of the WSL2 components and I got the same error

**UPDATE:** I see that it tried to change permissions for this folder: `D:\ProgramData\Docker`. But it could only remove all permissions:

```
removing ACLs except for SYSTEM and Administrators from D:\ProgramData\Docker
Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\Docker\config' is denied.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error with Docker Desktop 4.6.1, where it was trying to remove permissions on the `C:\ProgramData\Docker` directory, but didn't have permissions to. I tried to grant the permissions on that directory as mentioned in your answer @Nikolay-Makhonin, but apparently didn't have access to, even though I'm an admin on my machine.

What fixed it for me was just outright deleting the `C:\ProgramData\Docker` directory and then running the installer again.

Comment: Had the same issue with Docker Desktop 4.6.1.
Deleting your mentioned folder (which was practically empty in my case) helped the installion to go through.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was similar but in my case it was caused by a computer trojan. The trojan inserted a registry key inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and locked the registry folder.

I had to open `regedit` as administrator:
[image: Regedit as administrator]

Navigate to the folder:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

[image: Go to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and right click to go to permissions]

Right click -> Permissions -> Advanced.

There I saw that one of the permission entries was `Denied`. I had to change it to `allow`, delete the malignous key `RuntimeBroker`, and run the Docker Installation again.

[image: Docker Installation Successful]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I just added SYSTEM and Administrators rights to the D:\ProgramData\Docker folder manually.

Comment: I'm having this same issue on Docker Desktop 4.6.1. I suspect this would solve my problem, but unfortunately I don't have access to edit the permissions on that directory, even though I'm an admin on my machine :(

Comment: @deadlydog i was in the same boat as you. Local admin, but cant change permissions for that folder.
I solved it by deleted the folder entirely and rerunning the installation.

Comment: @AbdullahGheith yup, I solved my issue and left a new answer with this fix a couple days ago 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by re-downloading the installer. Apparently mine was corrupted. The downloads looked the same. They were the exact same size, etc... but the second downloaded one ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

In services I stopped Docker and in regedit I deleted the Docker folder from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.
Then the installation could continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it giving rights to the D:\ProgramData\Docker\config folder manually.

Comment: Already answered the same by others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you after trying to update from 4.11.1 to 4.12.0.
I noticed my docker was removed and not installed again, so I tried to install it manually without success.
I Found some tutorials saying to check my [WMI health](https://kb.acronis.com/content/62731), but it was consistent and what really solved my problem was to run a [chkdsk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer) /R to check and fix my os partition.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not correct BUT if you do it you're doing under your own risk!!!!!**

I solved this issue changing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run permission and adding "Everyone" role with all permissions (Remove this permissions when the installation is done)

Hope this is going to work for you.